# check admin rights inside python script

Tags: python, sudo

How to check that my python script is running under Administrator rights (sudo) under BSD-like OS? Need to display user-friendly warning in order it is executed without admin rights.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

How about this? Check if `uid == 0`:

```
[kbrandt@kbrandt-admin: ~] python -c 'import os; print os.getuid()'
196677

[kbrandt@kbrandt-admin: ~] sudo python -c 'import os; print os.getuid()'
0
```

Comment: I actually shortened it :-)  .  I use likewise open for Linux authentication, which creates a large UID by hashing the Windows SID.

Answer (score 3):

How about that one:

```
import os
username=os.system("whoami")
if username is not "root":
    print "You aren't root"
else:
    print "Hello, "+username
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't be tempted to match a username against the string "root".

Generally you will either have to provide less efficient callouts to obtain the textual representation of the UID or you will be relying on environment variables which may not be so trustworthy.